# Dynamic memory allocation in Eigen

Tags: c++11, eigen

I am using Eigen C++ library and I would like to see if my code uses dynamic memory allocation. According to documentation (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html), #defining the preprocessor macro "EIGEN_NO_MALLOC" should lead to an assertion failure if memory from the heap is allocated.

Thus I would expect that the following leads to a failure (because of using MatrixXcf):

#define EIGEN_NO_MALLOC 1

MatrixXcf A = MatrixXcf::Random(5,5);

But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Add the macro definition before you include the header files. The preprocessor processes its input in a strict top-to-bottom fashion.

Comment: Of course you're right. Thanks Some programmer dude!